# JQuery 2 function, after function (A) , can't active function (B)

Tags: jquery, ajax

My row data list page.

```
$('#search_ajax').click(function(){ showValues(); });
$(function() { 
  $('form').bind('submit',function(){ 
    showValues(); 
    return false; }); 
}); 
function showValues() { 
  $('#list_content').html(); //do someting
} 

$(".ajax_del").click(function() {     
  //dialog confirm del function
});
```

`$(".ajax_del").click(function()`

if click `button[class=ajax_del]` will be open a dialog show a confirm button

`$('#search_ajax').click(function()`

ajax search data and `html()` a div

If I click delete button on page. I can delete a data by ajax.

But, `$(".ajax_del").click(function()`  can't active after use ajax search

How can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must move `$(".ajax_del").click(function()` into `$(function() { })`

```
$(function() { 
  $('form').bind('submit',function(){ 
    showValues(); 
    return false; 
 }); 
  $(".ajax_del").click(function() {     
    //dialog confirm del function
  });
});
```

You should `$(document.body).on('click', '.ajax_del' ,function(){})` instead of `$(".ajax_del").click(function() {  })`

You can reference http://jsfiddle.net/dieuhd/ard03oot/

Comment: Thanks so much bluesky !  I change to $(document.body).on('click'... fixed that.